# Serverless creating Lambda in different account in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to upload Lambda function using [Serverless](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) framework but facing a weird issue.

Let's say I have 2 Accounts **Prod** and **Stg**.

Now I logged into Stg and created on a user profile, and then I used the configure method to add that in credentials folder. Now I created a fresh project using `serverless` and in YAML file I added the correct profile name and saved it. And then deployed a basic Lambda function. But I am seeing that Lambda function is getting created in Prod AWS Account. But I don't understand this behavior, coz Prod is no way related to Stg. But note that I do have some user profiles of Prod present in the credentials folder.

Please, someone, guide me on how something like this could be happening?

```
Yaml Settings

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  profile: server-admin
  region: us-east-1
```

Command used to deploy

```
sls deploy -v
```

Link checked - [Profile Problem in Serverless](https://forum.serverless.com/t/set-aws-profile/373/9)

Comment: So I found a work around by mentioning the profile on the fly - `sls deploy --aws-profile server-admin`

Comment: There are many ways to switch profiles, whether it's the CLI arg, an env var driving your profile field, or using `AWS_PROFILE` to switch to a preconfigured profile.

Comment: Ok I found the issue, somehow in my environment variable of windows 10 system PROD profile is set up. I think that takes priority over Serverless.yaml file settings

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the Prod is configured in your AWS CLI. Maybe in some point in the past you did something like `$ aws configure` and defined the default account.

check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

Comment: Ok I found the issue, somehow in my environment variable of windows 10 system PROD profile is set up. I think that takes priority over Serverless.yaml file settings